# Interfacing with MIPI CSI-2 camera sensors like the Omnivision OV2732?

Tags: fpga, camera, imageprocessing, image-sensor, csi

CSI-2 is used in pretty much every smartphone however I'm struggling to find much information on how most companies receive and control CSI-2 sensors. I understand there are NDAs. This is not for a hobbyist project, however I'm a beginner on this topic and the imaging industry.

Ideally I'm looking for some magical IC or SoC that will talk directly to the sensor, control most functionality automatically but allow some basic setup, and pipe video data out over some easy-to-use interface like LVDS RGB or something.

So far I've found [this](http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-cx3-programmable-mipi-csi-2-usb-30-camera-controller) and FPGA IP like [this](https://ip.cadence.com/ipportfolio/ip-portfolio-overview/interface-ip/mipi-ip/csi) however I'm unsure if these are unusual ways of doing this - what do most companies do?

Comment: Both links look good, ezUSB for the hobbyist who wants the cameras information (for processing etc) on a PC a easily as possible. The PHY is the proper solution for commercial applications. The FPGA IP core you found looks good, obviously phone companies will have there own firmware in interface with the PHY (they might even make there own PHY) but that's how they will do it.

Comment: https://www.mipi.org

Comment: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mipi_dphy/v3_1/pg202-mipi-dphy.pdf

Comment: Here are some IC's https://eu.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Interface-ICs/LVDS-Interface-IC/_/N-6j75b?P=1yodsht

Comment: Lattice has FPGAs that are designed for video interfacing.  See http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Solutions/SolutionCategories/MIPIInterfaces